# Socket.io with require.js async and io is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, requirejs, socket.io-1.0

Can someone explain to me why this work:

```
 <script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.4.js"></script>
 <script>
        var socket = io('http://nodeapp.herokuapp.com');
        console.log(socket);
 </script>
```

but this doesn't work:

```
 <script async src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.4.js"></script>
 <script>
        var socket = io('http://nodeapp.herokuapp.com');
        console.log(socket);
 </script>
```

Error is:

```
     Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Or how i can append socket.io library on client side with require.js and that in this case works ok (without error above).

Answer (score 4):

```
<script async ...
```

You explicitly ask the browser to not wait until it gets the scripts.

So it doesn't wait for the script to be fetched and executed before it goes to the next script. And thus `io` isn't yet defined when you go to

```
var socket = io('http://nodeapp.herokuapp.com');
```

[The MDN on script async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)

Comment: If I later in console try connect, error is still there.

Comment: Real question is why socket.io (1.0.x) loaded with require.js is not available globally? With version 0.9 everything is working fine...